# Why Can't I find the Dart language option in language selector when creating a new Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, installation

I installed all the requirements needed to run Flutter and Dart in Android Studio. Even the plugins (they're enabled). But still can't find the Dart option. I only find Java, Kotlin, and Groovy! And I can't even find it in the *+* button next.
How can I solve this?[image]

I tried surfing the net and couldn't find anything related. I used Bing AI too, but told me to uninstall it, restart Android Studio, and reinstall the plugins.
I haven't tried Bings solution, but I doubt it'll work.
If you think this might work, what are the steps I should go through to uninstall and reinstall the plugins.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the `New Flutter Project` Option
2. Now on the left side, select `Flutter` option from the Generators list
3. Specify flutter sdk path if needed and click on Next
4. On the next screen you can select android and ios language and other flutter project related settings